# return wrong EnrollNumber download attendance record via zkemkeeper

Tags: c#, dll

I m using zkemkeeper.dll to download attendance record from biometric device.
This is my code. sdwEnrollNumber return null or wrong string.
But same program works other compiuter and other devices.

```
if (device2.ReadGeneralLogData(1))//read all the attendance records to the memory
                {
                    string sdwEnrollNumber = "";
                    int idwVerifyMode = 0;
                    int idwInOutMode = 0;
                    int idwYear = 0;
                    int idwMonth = 0;
                    int idwDay = 0;
                    int idwHour = 0;
                    int idwMinute = 0;
                    int idwSecond = 0;
                    int idwWorkcode = 0;
                    while (device2.SSR_GetGeneralLogData(1, out sdwEnrollNumber, out idwVerifyMode,
                               out idwInOutMode, out idwYear, out idwMonth, out idwDay, out idwHour, out idwMinute, out idwSecond, ref idwWorkcode))//get records from the memory
                    {
                        devece2_log(deviceIp, sdwEnrollNumber, 0, idwInOutMode, idwVerifyMode, idwYear, idwMonth, idwHour, idwHour, idwMinute, idwSecond, idwWorkcode);
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

devices is not same use this GetGeneralExtLogData

```
while (device2FingersList["device_" + deviceIp].GetGeneralExtLogData(1, ref idwEnrollNumber, ref idwVerifyMode, ref idwInOutMode,
                             ref idwYear, ref idwMonth, ref idwDay, ref idwHour, ref idwMinute, ref idwSecond, ref idwWorkCode, ref idwReserved))//get records from the memory
                    {
                        devece2_log(deviceIp, idwEnrollNumber.ToString(), 0, idwInOutMode, idwVerifyMode, idwYear, idwMonth, idwDay, idwHour, idwMinute, idwSecond, idwWorkCode, "BAW");
                    }
```